# Calculating a range of User Inputed values (Unspecified amount) in a textbox created grid

Tags: c#, spreadsheet, calculation

In this assignment I have to create a spreadsheet like excel without importing a library. Now So far I created a grid of 26x26 textboxes (USING CODE), created the indexed rows and alphabet indexed columns. (All of this using a class named Cellfields as a template)

Gave the names (A1,A2,A3 etc) to each cell. and created a formula bar up top.

then I created an if statement that if what the user writes.SubString(0) == to "=" (Meaning the start of a formula),

it will then go to a switch to read the other input the user entered, meaning if user enters =Sum(A1:A3) it will calculate the sum of cells A1,A2,A3.

Now since the calculated cells required are unspecified, I am unable to find a solution to how to calculate a range of values online, as all you can find online are how to import libraries.

I Did try a few things but were immediately removed. I am trying to create a method for it however, have been staring at laptop for the past 3 days.

Comment: Why are you using Textboxes, why not Datagrid?

Comment: assignment requirements :/

Answer (score 0):

So you already have a matrix of 26x26 Textboxes, I assume they would be arranged in a Grid, say the name of your Grid is "gridCells".
Now, Users will click on a Cell (actually textbox) and then go to the Formula Bar and type a formula. So On `GotFocus` of the textboxes, let the textbox remain "Selected", in the sense keep the reference at form level also may be Highlight the Border to show that this is the currently selected cell. This will help you know which Textbox to apply the formula.
Now, when someone types "=Sum(A1:A3)" in the Formula Bar, you would parse the formula, identify it is a "Sum" operation and find out the names of the Textboxes A1, A2 & A3.

From your post looks like you are done this far. Now write a function as below (Not bothering about performance etc. right now).

```
private String GetValueOfCell(String cellName)
{
     foreach (var control in gridCells.Children.OfType<TextBox>())
         if (control.Name.Equals(cellName))
              return control.Text;
     return "";
 }
```

Call this function for all 3 Textboxes, like this:

```
String value = GetValueOfCell("A1");
```

And if the value is not empty and can be parsed as int/double, keep doing the Sum and finally store the value in the Text property of our highlighted Textbox.
Hint: You might also want to Save the Formula on the highlighted textbox, because this value goes into the Text property you can use the Tag property to hold the formula.

Comment: thank you for this but the string value = GetValueOfCell("*")(I will not know which one the user inputed since we have a total of 676 cells

Comment: When you create your TextBoxes name them A1, A2....B1, B2.....and so on. Then Parse the formula for eg. "=Sum(A1:A3)" in this case you the text inside Bracket is A1:A3, so you know that you have to Sum A1 to A3.